# How to remove Linux software RAID MD device?

Tags: partitioning, raid, opensuse, mdadm

I'm trying to *install openSUSE 12.3 on the new server*. It is [this machine](http://www.oracle.com/us/products/servers-storage/servers/netra/netra-x4270-server/overview/index.html).

There are 2 HDDs connected to the SAS controller. What I want to achieve is a NON-RAID configuration where 1.HDD is used for swap and root partitions and 2.HDD will contain /home partition. But when I start setup process I can see that partitioning utility shows that there are present 4 md devices in the system like: */dev/md124* ...

Two of those devices can be removed but remaining ones cannot. I have also tried the GParted live distro to remove those partitions and create desired layout but when I committed all of the changes there it ended up with error. So the new partitions were not created.

Comment: You don't have an option when starting the install to remove any existing partitions on the disks?

Comment: No, when installing the openSUSE 12.3 there is no such option.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Well, this is how I solved my problem. I found some steps how to remove MD device.

1. In the openSUSE 12.3 installer, switch to the console.
2. List your devices: `# df -kh`
3. Make sure the devices are unmounted: `# umount /dev/md124`
4. Check the details: `# mdadm --detail /dev/md124`
5. Stop the device: `# mdadm -S /dev/md124`
6. Zero out the superblocks of physical devices that belong to the MD device:
   `# mdadm --zero-superblock /dev/sdb1`
7. Switch back to the installer.
8. In the partitioning part of installer, refresh devices.
9. The MD devices should not be there now.

Comment: @Nathan Smith:  Thanks for adding the code formatting, but please don’t make things bold (or italic) unless you have a really good reason.

Answer (score 0):

If there was an "real" SAS RAID set up you should go through corresponding setup utility of raid controller which is usually available after (or during) BIOS POST. Simply destroy array there.

See server manual for details.

Comment: Yes, I have checked also the bios of the SAS controller and it seems that no raid array is configured there. So the problem must be somewhere else.

Comment: md devices are linux software raid.

Comment: @raul: add the output of /proc/mdstat to the question

Comment: ok, I can do this once I have access to the server room again (tomorrow)